# photoswipe jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, photoswipe

How do I invoke the next/prev methods? I need to separate the buttons in more and cannot hold all the buttons in the toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [the source code on Guthub](https://github.com/codecomputerlove/PhotoSwipe/blob/master/src/photoswipe.class.js), I don't know Photoswipe but I had a glance at the source and found the following:

```
    /*
     * Function: previous
     */
    previous: function(){

        if (this.isZoomActive()){
            return;
        }

        if (!Util.isNothing(this.carousel)){
            this.carousel.previous();
        }

    },



    /*
     * Function: next
     */
    next: function(){

        if (this.isZoomActive()){
            return;
        }

        if (!Util.isNothing(this.carousel)){
            this.carousel.next();
        }

    }
```

You might want to check out the respective carousel functions referenced in the code above.

Comment: I had already seen this methods. But my problem is to invoke this methods.
For example, I create a button and this must do an action method (for example Next)

Comment: You might want to have another look at @generalchaos answer below, he seems to have solved it for you. If that's the case you should accept his answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The PhotoSwipe documentation shows you how to instantiate the code:

```
// Set up PhotoSwipe with all anchor tags in the Gallery container 
$(document).ready(function(){

    var myPhotoSwipe = $("#Gallery a").photoSwipe({ enableMouseWheel: false , enableKeyboard: false });

});
```

To go to the next image, simple call 'next' on your photoSwipe instance as such:

```
myPhotoSwipe.next();
```

OR 'previous' to go back

```
myPhotoSwipe.previous();
```

as mentioned by Denoir (thanks!).

Hope this helps.
Cheers.